# R: "deaccumulate" sum vector without a for loop

Tags: r, optimization, cumulative-sum

In cases when we have a vector and want to accumulate its number, we use `cumsum`:

```
vec = c(0,3,3,1,1,3)
vec.sum = cumsum(vec)

vec.sum
[1]  0  3  6  7  8 11
```

What about when we want the opposite? A for loop does the trick, but is there a more efficient way to do this, specially with large vectors?

```
for (i in length(vec.sum):2) {
  vec.sum[i] = vec.sum[i] - vec.sum[i-1]
}

vec.sum
[1] 0 3 3 1 1 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c(vec.sum[1], diff(vec.sum))
#[1] 0 3 3 1 1 3
```

Or

```
 c(vec.sum[1],vec.sum[-1]-vec.sum[-length(vec.sum)])
 #[1] 0 3 3 1 1 3
```

Comment: Could be  `c(vec.sum[1], diff(vec.sum))`. Then `vec[1]` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks, @akrun! The answer was so obvious I feel like a moron. I didn't know the `diff` function

Comment: @Bernardo  I use `diff` especially for creating logical indexes.  It is very useful function.